# android generic SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, reflection, sqliteopenhelper, invocationhandler

i developed a small java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler that intercepts method calls (from a json webservice) and cache the results to a local SQLite db. if there is no internet connection results are read from local cache.

everything works fine; my problem is the following:

every method intercepted can return a different entity, and i save using reflection each entity on a different table. i don't know in advance all the tables i need to create, so every time i create a SQLiteOpenHelper that "create table if not exists {ENTITY_NAME}", and every time i increase the database version by 1 so the method onUpgrade is called.

this works on development environment but i don't like that at all.

someone can recommend a better solution to update the database with new tables?

thank you

Comment: can you serialize your entities to a string? that way you can have one table with a type column and the data serialized.

Comment: i can do but i want to save the single entities and not the full method result, so if i call service.getAllEmployees() with internet connection the objects are cached, and then service.getEmployeeById("1") offline i can read the object from cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  `mYourDbHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("CREATE TABLE ....")` from where you need to create another table